# Logical Consequence - Equivalent Assertions

Tags: satisfiability, artificial-intelligence, sets, propositional-logic, equality

I have the following slide in my notes and I'm having trouble understanding how the three assertions are equivalent. I understand to a degree how the 2nd and 3rd assertions are equivalent, but the equivalence between the 1st and 3rd as well as the 1st and 2nd isn't really explained well here. Am I missing something? Is the first exercise relevant to this problem?

[image: Proof]

Answer (score 0):

Yes they all are equivalent. Using **standard rules of inference i.e. Modus Ponen, Modus Tollen, Hypothetical syllogism and Fallacies**, which are just ways to infer logical consequences of a set of formulas, you can resolve a set of clauses(formulas) to get a resolvent. In this case using the rules of inference, one needs to arrive at the given resolvent clause $G$ to show that it is satisfiable.

Let's try to prove $Q$ is a logical consequence of $\left \{ P, P\rightarrow Q \right \}$ using all three methods.

**Method 1**

$\left \{ P, P\rightarrow Q \right \} = \left \{ P, \sim P\vee Q \right \}$.

Taking Logical AND of these clauses we get

$P\wedge \left ( \sim P\vee Q \right )\Rightarrow \left ( P\wedge\sim P \right )\vee \left ( P\wedge Q \right )\Rightarrow P\wedge Q$.

Here we get the $Q$ as one of the resolvents which is enough to prove that $Q$ is a logical consequence of the given set of formulas, why you may ask, because you started with a conjunction of a set of formulas and ended up with another conjunction of a set of formulas,  using laws of logic, and if the former was true the latter has to be true and hence $Q$ is true as well. Similarly $P$ is a logical consequence, although a trivial one.

**Method 2**

We go by the definition, and using above calculations we arrive at $ P\wedge Q$. Now we need to check $ P\wedge Q\rightarrow Q $

$\left ( P\wedge Q \right )\rightarrow Q \Rightarrow \sim \left ( P\wedge Q \right )\vee Q\Rightarrow \sim P\vee \sim Q\vee Q\Rightarrow T$

**Method 3**

Again by definition, and using above calculations we arrive at $P\wedge Q\wedge \sim P\Rightarrow Q\wedge F\Rightarrow F$. This is simply negation of the formula used in method 2.

For method 2 and 3 yes you can use the truth table and yes it is tedious so you can use laws of logic, but even using that you'll end up with additional steps to prove it completely(as done in calculations above), and hence we have the standard rules of inference which help you come to the conclusion in a much more concise manner.